# Why is casting to int giving me 8 instead of 0?

Tags: java, types, casting, int, long-integer

Sorry if this is simple. This has been confusing me for some time now. In the following code:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long a = 10000000000L;
        System.out.println(a % 10);
    }
}
```

I get an output of 0 which is what I expected. But when I cast to int like this,

```
public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            long a = 10000000000L;
            System.out.println((int)a % 10);
        }
}
```

I get 8 as output instead of 0. I do not understand what is happening. Why is 0 turning into 8 after casting?

Comment: Because (int) a % 10 = 1410065408 % 10 = 8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That happens because first is casting the value of `a` to int and then doing the module.

What you want to do is:

```
public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            long a = 10000000000L;
            System.out.println((int)(a % 10));
        }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping. I had completely forgotten about the brackets.

Comment: No worries. I'm glad I could help

Answer (score 3):

As you are casting the `long` into `int`. And the value of `long` is beyond the range of `int` *(-2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647)*. So when you try to cast it and store it in `int` data type than the JVM will simply round it of into the range of `int` data type. And the value which will be stored in `int` is *1410065408*.

Now if you do the 1410065408 % 10 = 8.

You can try below program to verify the same.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long a = 10000000000L;
        int b = (int) a; 
        System.out.println(b);  // here it will print 1410065408 
        System.out.println(b % 10);  //so here it's 8
    }
}
```